# Construction of a group in Magma

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, magma-cas

I need to construct the following group in Magma: given $H=(C_2)^3 \rtimes (C_7 \rtimes C_3) \times C_3$ (so $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(168,43)\times C_3$), there is a non-split central extension by $C_3$. We call it $\hat{H} = (C_2)^3 \rtimes (C_7 \rtimes 3^{1+2}_+)$.

Given $\hat{N}=A_4=\operatorname{SmallGroup}(12,3)$ we can consider its normal subgroup $N = C_2 \times C_2$.

I want to build an extension of $H \times N$ by $C_3$ that contains both $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{N}$ (so I am identifying the two $C_3$s that give these actions)

When the extensions are split, I usually do this kind of thing by constructing the direct product $G= \hat{H} \times \hat{N}$ and then taking normal subgroups $H$ and $N$ and elements  $x \in \hat{H}\setminus H$ and $y \in \hat{N}\setminus N$ that give the action of the corresponding extensions, and using $$\operatorname{sub}<G | H, N, x*y>;$$

but in this case I honestly have no clue since $C_3$ does not "act" on $H$.

An answer in GAP would also be fine, as I just need to examine certain invariants of this group.

Comment: I don't understand your description of the extension that you want to construct. The phrase "extension of $X$ by $Y$" is ambiguous. Which of $X$ and $Y$ is the normal subgroups and which is the quotient? Your group $\hat{H}$ seems to have a subgroup $C_3$ with quotient $H$, whereas $\hat{N}$ has the $C_3$ as the quotient, so I have no idea what you mean by an extension of $H \times N$ by $C_3$.

Comment: $H \times N$ should be the normal subgroup. Maybe I am wrong about the "centrality" of the extension by that $C_3$? What I mean is that $\hat{H} = (C_2)^5 \rtimes SmallGroup(189,8)$ [link](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/163/C7sHe3.html) where the center acts trivially, and $\hat{N}=A_4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered that Magma supports "GroupNames", so I tried the following instruction

`G:=Group("C2^5:C7:He3");`

and then I checked some properties:

`Order(G);
Center(G);
Centraliser(G,Sylow(G,7));
Centraliser(G,Sylow(G,2));
T:=Sylow(G,3);
Centraliser(G,T.1);
Centraliser(G,T.2);
Centraliser(G,T.1*T.2);`

...and it seems that this is indeed my group.

Comment: Same! Today my life became easier

Comment: There might be several groups with the same structure, even if one assumes nontrivial actions.

Comment: Absolutely, but the one Magma picks happens to have an example of the invariants I was looking for (if there are more with the properties I checked they are probably all examples)